# Crashing android app while taking screenshot in One Plus 7 Pro [React-Native]

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing app in react-native, I am facing an issue whenever I take screenshot in android from any screen of app, it is getting crash in One Plus 7 Pro.

**Crash Report from Android Studio**

```
2019-07-19 12:22:15.728 13778-13778/? E/SensorManager: registerListenerImpl sensorName:lsm6dsm Accelerometer Non-wakeup,isWakeUpSensor:false,callingApp: com.abcd,callingPid:13778,callingUid:10279
2019-07-19 12:22:15.913 13778-13778/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:22:15.913 13778-13778/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:22:15.963 13778-13829/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:22:15.963 13778-13829/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:22:45.318 13778-13778/com.abcd E/SensorManager: unregisterListenerImpl callingApp: com.abcd,callingPid:13778,callingUid:10279
2019-07-19 12:23:12.210 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.fps.history.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:12.210 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:12.210 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:12.214 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:12.214 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:23.699 13778-13778/com.abcd E/SensorManager: registerListenerImpl sensorName:lsm6dsm Accelerometer Non-wakeup,isWakeUpSensor:false,callingApp: com.abcd,callingPid:13778,callingUid:10279
2019-07-19 12:23:48.223 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.fps.history.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:48.223 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:48.223 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:48.262 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:48.262 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:52.916 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.fps.history.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:52.916 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:52.916 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:52.984 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
2019-07-19 12:23:52.984 13778-13829/com.abcd E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
```

**Crash Report from React- Native Console**

```
ExceptionsManager.js:84 Cannot record touch end without a touch start.
Touch End: Touch Bank: %s
 {"identifier":2,"pageX":347.10205078125,"pageY":149.87754821777344,"timestamp":68288113} [{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":233.79591369628906,"startPageY":171.10203552246094,"startTimeStamp":68288102,"currentPageX":233.79591369628906,"currentPageY":171.10203552246094,"currentTimeStamp":68288113,"previousPageX":233.79591369628906,"previousPageY":171.10203552246094,"previousTimeStamp":68288102},{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":127.34693908691406,"startPageY":220.7346954345703,"startTimeStamp":68288105,"currentPageX":127.34693908691406,"currentPageY":220.7346954345703,"currentTimeStamp":68288113,"previousPageX":127.34693908691406,"previousPageY":220.7346954345703,"previousTimeStamp":68288105}]
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ ExceptionsManager.js:84
console.error @ YellowBox.js:59
recordTouchEnd @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1676
recordTouchTrack @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1714
extractEvents @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2255
extractEvents @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:877
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:931
(anonymous) @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2620
batchedUpdates$1 @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14041
batchedUpdates @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2525
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2619
receiveTouches @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2695
__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:344
(anonymous) @ MessageQueue.js:107
__guard @ MessageQueue.js:291
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:106
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
2ExceptionsManager.js:84 Cannot record touch end without a touch start.
Touch End: Touch Bank: %s
 {"identifier":2,"pageX":347.10205078125,"pageY":149.87754821777344,"timestamp":68288113} [{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":233.79591369628906,"startPageY":171.10203552246094,"startTimeStamp":68288102,"currentPageX":233.79591369628906,"currentPageY":171.10203552246094,"currentTimeStamp":68288113,"previousPageX":233.79591369628906,"previousPageY":171.10203552246094,"previousTimeStamp":68288113},{"touchActive":false,"startPageX":127.34693908691406,"startPageY":220.7346954345703,"startTimeStamp":68288105,"currentPageX":127.34693908691406,"currentPageY":220.7346954345703,"currentTimeStamp":68288113,"previousPageX":127.34693908691406,"previousPageY":220.7346954345703,"previousTimeStamp":68288113}]
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ ExceptionsManager.js:84
console.error @ YellowBox.js:59
recordTouchEnd @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1676
recordTouchTrack @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1714
extractEvents @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2255
extractEvents @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:877
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:931
(anonymous) @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2620
batchedUpdates$1 @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14041
batchedUpdates @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2525
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2619
receiveTouches @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2695
__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:344
(anonymous) @ MessageQueue.js:107
__guard @ MessageQueue.js:291
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:106
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-secure-key-store": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "6.5.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-rend
```

I am unable to reach out to the exact solution.

Device has Android 9 Version and tried with other devices which has same Android Version but there is no crash with any of them.fie

Please suggest me how I can fix this issue.

Comment: there is no crash info in log

Comment: Got similar problems on huawei/xiaomi devices when trying to do a 3-fingers-slide screenshot. Please update react-native at least to 0.59.10

Comment: I got the solution by adding the line in root file
console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am not getting this issue after adding only single line in my code - 
**console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;**

Comment: How to add this line in android studio?

Comment: @HarshSuvagiya sorry for delay, you can add this line in your root file like App.js or in Landing js file.