# EXCEPTION - DB access is requested even when user has either not authenticated yet or has been sign out

Tags: android, android-studio

We are trying to debug an APK using Android studio and are coming up with the following errors. We tried launching it but cannot pass the initial signing screen without it receiving the following errors before the app restarts itself. Please help in fixing the exception.

Device being used: 1+ Pro

**Logcat Message :**

```
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 3bc9a6f, I21de9e011e
    Build Date                       : 02/25/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.19.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.1.R1.09.00.00.461.091
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    Build Config                     : S P 6.0.9 AArch64
.....

E/AppCenter: Distribute needs to be started before it can be used.
E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
    Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
E/Application: ProcessId: 14561, Thread: Pool-WorkManager-Thread-1, EXCEPTION - DB access is requested even when user has either not authenticated yet or has been sign out.
```

Comment: Is this a react native app?

Comment: Yes, it has react native code

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57139796/2029566)?